# Mips Recursive Function Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000001

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips

I am currently writing c program that can translate my own language grammar into mips code.

```
int i;
int b;
int add() {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = i + 1;
        return add();
    }
    return i;
}

i = 0;
b = add();
```

But my issue is in mips where I am running into memory address issues on how to properly handle recursion functions. 
I know my C code isn't optimizing mips but please ignore that. 
How can I fix this small mips program so I can handle other types of recursive functions.

```
        .text
        .globl          main
main:
        li              $t0, 0
        sw              $t0, i
        subu            $sp, $sp, 0
        jal             add
        addu            $sp, $sp, 0
        move            $t0, $v1
        sw              $t0, b
        li              $v0, 10
        syscall
add:
        subu            $sp, $sp, 4
        sw              $ra, ($sp)
        lw              $t0, i
        li              $t1, 10
        slt             $t2, $t0, $t1
        beq             $t2, 0, L1
        lw              $t0, i
        li              $t1, 1
        add             $t3, $t0, $t1
        sw              $t3, i
        subu            $sp, $sp, 4
        sw              $t2, 4($sp)
        jal             add
        lw              $t2, 4($sp)
        addu            $sp, $sp, 4
        move            $t0, $v1
        move            $v1, $t0
L1:
        lw              $t0, i
        move            $v1, $t0
        lw              $ra, ($sp)
        addu            $sp, $sp, 4
        jr              $ra
        .data
        .align          4
i:      .word           0
b:      .word           0
```

Any suggestions or answers would be much appreciated!

Comment: *invalid program counter value: 0x00000001* means your code jumped to that address. Presumably you overwrote a saved return address on the stack because that's not a value `jal` could have written to `$ra`.  (Not in the right range, and not aligned by 4.)  Use the debugger in MARS or SPIM to single-step your code and find out what happens to registers / memory right before that bad jump.

Comment: Also, `move $t0, $v1`  then `move $v1, $t0` is useless.  The first instruction already makes both registers equal.  If that was supposed to be a swap then you need a temporary.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy comments! Thanks for pointing out that useless move as I think that code is produced more because I'm not sure how to generate mips code for recursion just yet.  Anyway, I will test out the debugger in MARS to see where I am overwriting $ra.

Comment: One time, you allocate 4 bytes of stack space and store into `0($sp)`, which is the newly allocated space, but another time you allocate 4 bytes of stack space and store into `4($sp)`, which is not the newly allocated stack space.